Validation occcurs even when the fields are filled
User update function in laravel controller displays a 422 status code even when the fields are filled, i tried in postman and even the frontend react. Am using laravel as a rest api and react as a frontend. The validation errors keeps displaying even if the fields are filled. Its really bugging me i have tried every possible alternatives that i know
Here is the controller method code.
public function updateuser(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,username,' . $user->id,
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . $user->id,
            'profile_image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Validation failed',
                'errors' => $validator->errors()
            ], 422);
        }

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->username = $request->input('username');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');

        if ($request->hasFile('profile_image')) {
            if ($user->profile_image) {
                Storage::delete('public/profile_images/' . $user->profile_image);
            }

            $imagePath = $request->file('profile_image')->store('profile_images', 'public');
            $user->profile_image = basename($imagePath);
        }

        $user->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User profile updated.',
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }

User model code.
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'profile_image',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'password' => 'hashed',
        ];
    }
}

and the api route.

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::put('/update/{username}', [AuthController::class, 'updateuser']);
});

I checked the code, maybe i can use another perspective.

Have you tried dumping all the data before the request, mkae you you are getting what you expect?

You will have to change the Rest Method.
the issue here is that the form will always be empty therefore resulting in a 422 missing attributes and this is because the PUT method with PHP do not support multipart/form-data updates.

Solutions :
use POST instead of PUT in laravel and react
or use _method=PUT as form data param and call it using POST

source :
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing
